# Picture fill symbol fails with a polygon graphic

Tags: arcobjects, vbscript

The following code snippet successfully draws a graphic polygon and fills it with the specified picture fill symbol.  When the x values for all of the points are made negative and a repeat call to the snippet is made, the polygon is symbolized but it is not visible.  However, when you grab one of the resizing grips of the polygon graphic and stretch it a little the symbolization becomes visible.   Can anyone vouch for this behavior?  Is this a bug with ArcGIS maybe? I'm completely baffled etc.

```vb
Dim pGC As IGraphicsContainer
pGC = pMap

Dim oPoint As IPoint

Dim pPolygon As IPointCollection
pPolygon = New Polygon

oPoint.PutCoords(150, 120)
pPolygon.AddPoint(oPoint)

oPoint = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
oPoint.PutCoords(160, 120)
pPolygon.AddPoint(oPoint)

oPoint = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
oPoint.PutCoords(160, 115)
pPolygon.AddPoint(oPoint)

oPoint = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
oPoint.PutCoords(150, 115)
pPolygon.AddPoint(oPoint)

oPoint = New ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry.Point
oPoint.PutCoords(150, 120)
pPolygon.AddPoint(oPoint)

Dim pElement As IElement
pElement = New PolygonElement
pElement.Geometry = pPolygon

Dim pFillShapeElement As IFillShapeElement
pFillShapeElement = pElement

Dim pPictureFillSymbol As IPictureFillSymbol
pPictureFillSymbol = New PictureFillSymbol
pPictureFillSymbol.CreateFillSymbolFromFile(esriIPictureType.esriIPictureBitmap, clsAppHelper.GetArcGISInstallDir & "styles\pictures\smallwave.bmp")

pFillShapeElement.Symbol = pPictureFillSymbol
pGC.AddElement(pElement, 0)
pMxDoc.ActiveView.Refresh()
```